# How to find a record both by id and query parameters in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to use ember-data to send a request via id and query parameters to an endpoint. The end output of the ajax call would be `http://api.example.com/invoices/1?key=value`. As far as I know, ember-data's `store` doesn't have a native way to find by both id and query parameters (neither of the following worked):

```
// outputs http://api.example/com/invoices/1
this.store.find('invoice', 1);

// outputs http://api.example.com/invoices?id=1&key=value
this.store.find('invoice, {id: 1, key: value});
```

Instead, I've been attempting to modify the invoice adapter. Our backend is Django, so we're using the `ActiveModelAdapter`. I want to override the method that builds the url so that if `id` is present in the `query` object, it will automatically remove it and append it to the url instead before turning the rest of the `query` object into url parameters.

The only problem is that I can't figure out which method to override. I've looked at the docs for `ActiveModelAdapter` [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelAdapter.html), and I've tried overriding the `findRecord`, `buildUrl`, `urlForFind`, and `urlForQuery` methods, but none of them are getting called for some reason (I've tried logging via `console.log` and `Ember.debug`). I know the adapter is working correctly because the `namespace` is working.

Here's my adapter file:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'v1',
  host: config.apiUrl,

  // taken straight from the build-url-mixin and modified
  // very slightly to test for logging
  urlForFindRecord: function(id, modelName, snapshot) {
    Ember.debug('urlForFindRecord is being called');

    if (this.urlForFind !== urlForFind) {
      Ember.deprecate('BuildURLMixin#urlForFind has been deprecated and renamed to `urlForFindRecord`.');
      return this.urlForFind(id, modelName, snapshot);
    }
    return this._buildURL(modelName, id);
  },

  // taken straight from the build-url-mixin and modified
  // very slightly to test for logging
  findRecord: function(store, type, id, snapshot) {
    Ember.debug('findRecord is being called');

    var find = RestAdapter.prototype.find;
    if (find !== this.find) {
      Ember.deprecate('RestAdapter#find has been deprecated and renamed to `findRecord`.');
      return this.find(store, type, id, snapshot);
    }
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'findRecord'), 'GET');
  },

  // taken straight from the build-url-mixin and modified
  // very slightly to test for logging
  urlForQuery: function(query, modelName) {
    Ember.debug('urlForQuery is being called');

    if (this.urlForFindQuery !== urlForFindQuery) {
      Ember.deprecate('BuildURLMixin#urlForFindQuery has been deprecated and renamed to `urlForQuery`.');
      return this.urlForFindQuery(query, modelName);
    }
    return this._buildURL(modelName);
  },

  // taken straight from the build-url-mixin and modified
  // very slightly to test for logging
  _buildURL: function(modelName, id) {
    Ember.debug('_buildURL is being called');

    var url = [];
    var host = get(this, 'host');
    var prefix = this.urlPrefix();
    var path;

    if (modelName) {
      path = this.pathForType(modelName);
      if (path) { url.push(path); }
    }

    if (id) { url.push(encodeURIComponent(id)); }
    if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url && url.charAt(0) !== '/') {
      url = '/' + url;
    }

    return url;
  },
});
```

**Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without overriding adapter methods? And if not, what method(s) do I need to override?**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.store.findQueryOne('invoice', 1, { key: value });

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2584

Comment: Just an update, `findQueryOne` seems to be gone again from Ember data. Not sure what the alternative is

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I switched to `adapterOptions` and `urlForFindRecord`. You can find more information here https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3596

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll check it out.